# Selenium webdriver is getting log entries for the server event "500 internal server error" when using GetLog(LogType.Browser)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

After I have been doing any automated task with selenium webdriver, I check the javascript log to see if anything unexpected has happened.

To do that, I am using

```
browser.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser).Where(l=>l.Level != LogLevel.Warning);
```

(This will only give me critical log entries).

Why am I also getting log entries for 500 internal server error?

Shouldn´t that belong to the logkind `LogType.Server`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LogType.Browser` is intended to show the javascript errors that you can observe in browser's JS-console. So if the log message appears in that console, then you'll see such the message there.

`LogType.Server` does not refer to the server component of your application under test. It defines the log messages that are produced by Selenium server component.

`LogType.Client`, for example, defines the messages that are produced by Selenium client-side protocol that you use in your code.

**UPD:**

- [Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) you can find some details on what client and what server is
- [Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Logging) you can find some details on how logging is implemented in Selenium

Comment: And LogType.Client will include the javascripts error then?

Comment: Getting `unknown error: log type 'client' not found
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)`

Comment: Log type does not define the type of error you expect to get. It is rather the place where the log entry appears. Anything related to js issues may or may not appear in client log, depending on the particular implementation. However it is more natural to expect sich kind of errors in BROWSER logs. See some references in my answer update